# How to merge column labels in barplot in R (a stacked barplot)?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

my data in R is look like this:

```
    1-12 1-12 1-15 1-15 1-20 1-20 2-6 2-6 3-1-1 3-1-1 3-1 3-1 3-2 3-2 3-3 3-3
N    0    0   14    0   17    0   9   0    27     0   9   0  13   0  33   0
P    0    0    0   12    0   12   0   5     0    13   0   6   0   0   0   9
F    0    0    0    0    0    0   0   2     0    14   0   0   0   6   0  20
```

By dput(data) the result in R is:

```
    structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 
17L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 2L, 27L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 13L, 14L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 
33L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 20L), .Dim = c(3L, 16L), .Dimnames = list(
c("N", "P", "F"), c("1-12", "1-12", "1-15", "1-15", "1-20", 
"1-20", "2-6", "2-6", "3-1-1", "3-1-1", "3-1", "3-1", "3-2", 
"3-2", "3-3", "3-3")))
```

and my code is:

```
barplot(data,space=c(1,0.25),legend=rownames(data),col=c('white','black','grey'),las=2)
```

it looks like a normal bar plot, each column has a label at the bottom...

But, there are too many labels in the x-axis, and I want to merge the names of two columns into one(since they have the same name), i.e, in the middle of first two columns, there is only one label "1-12" at the bottom, so there will be eight labels in total. How can I make this change?

Many thanks!

Comment: I don't feel like guessing what structure this might be and then trying to piece it together, matrix or malformed data.frame or whatever, so why don't you post dput(.) on that object, please?

Comment: @Dwin - agreed. It has to be a `matrix` however if `barplot` is already working.

Comment: yes, since I still can't put images in the question, I post dput()

Answer (score 2):

If you just wish to have the centred labels under each group, you could do something like:

```
# suppress the x-axis and save your original plot's bar locations
bp <- barplot(data,space=c(1,0.25),legend=rownames(data),
             col=c('white','black','grey'),las=2,
             xaxt="n")

# draw a new axis using these values
axis(1,at=rowMeans(matrix(bp,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)),
     labels=unique(colnames(data)),lty=0)
```

[image]

*Ignoring the overlapping legend of course... which can be fixed by placing it better using `legend.args` in the original `barplot` call*

Comment: Thanks for suggestion about dput! I put the result of dput in the question so you can look at it... actually I use data=rbind(F,P,N) and then use colnames(data)=c("1-12","1-15","1-20") to rename the columns.
However, I didn't want to produce a column that stacks P,F,N together, my bar plot is like all the "N" is in a single column and "F" "N" are grouped into one column. There's nothing to do with the barplot, I just want to change the labels of x-axis.

Comment: @user2687500 - I have edited to hopefully better address your question.